# AngularJS x Angular 2 x Angular 4

Tags: angular

Tenho observado uma pequena controvérsia com estes termos no título da pergunta. 
Muitas pessoas tem se referido ao Angular 2 em diante como "AngularJS" o que no meu ponto de vista está errado, o correto a seria somente "Angular" a partir da versão 2 em diante. E também vejo pessoas se referindo ao "AngularJS 1.x" como "Angular". O que me deixou deveras confuso, e fiz a seguinte pesquisa no Google Trends.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como o angular 2 foi reescrito e é um framework novo, existe algum aspecto técnico que justifique a baixa adoção ou esta pesquisa no Google Trends só reflete a confusão de termos ?

Comment: Como é o gráfico de "angular"?

Comment: Fica oscilando entre angularJS, porem dei uma pesquisa e é um termo genérico, começa a aparecer como resultado "conjugação do verbo angular" , "medida", "skate em movimeto angular", estas coisas.

Comment: Um depoimento pessoal: quando ainda não existia o Angular 2, usei AngularJS em alguns projetos, e muitas vezes chamei só de "angular". Pior, quando saiu o Angular 2 eu não me interessei e continuei chamando todos eles de "angular". O fato é que os desenvolvedores do Angular fizeram essa lambança com os nomes e geraram a confusão toda.

Comment: Essa confusão acontece frequentemente no trends, como muitas linguagens não possui tópicos elas se confundem com outras coisas, como a linguagem python, seus resultados abrangem a serpente Pythonidae(Python), em relação a angular2, não foi amplamente adotado, mas não tão pouco como o trends indica